# Выполнить двойной обход цикла в таске

Tags: ansible, task

Есть таск типа:

```
- name: 'Copy test'
  template: src=test dest=/tmp/test_{{item}}_{{item_key}}
 with_sequence:                                                                                     
    - start=1 end=3 format=test%02x 
    - with_items: 
        - item_key_1
        - item_key_2
```

и его темплейт:

`item number = {{item}}
 item key = {{item_key}}`

результатом хочу получить в папке tmp файлы типа:

`/tmp/test_1_item_key_1
/tmp/test_1_item_key_2
/tmp/test_2_item_key_1
/tmp/test_2_item_key_2
/tmp/test_3_item_key_1
/tmp/test_3_item_key_2`

Comment: Не очень понятно, как у соответствуют номера файлов строкам из списка: файлов 6, а строк 3.

Comment: Вот в этом вся проблема) Это просто пример - но в общем случае - они никак линейно никак не соответствуют.
Тоесть с примером 6 разных файлов записать 6 строк - проблем бы не было)
Проблема когда их количество не равно - получается что для обхода нужен двойной цикл.

Comment: Опишите нужную вам логику псевдокодом – например, есть входные параметры N и M, нужно получить N файлов test1..testN, содержащих M строк каждый... как-то так? иначе непонятно чего вы хотите достичь.

Comment: понятнее не стало, честно говоря. для вложенного цикла с предопределенными заранее данными есть `with_nested`.

Comment: переформулировал и забыл сделать апдейт) сейчас вопрос обновлен)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `with_nested`:

```
- name: 'Copy test'
  template:
    src: test
    dest: "/tmp/test_{{item.0}}_{{item.1}}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ lookup('sequence', 'start=1 end=3 format=test%02x', wantlist=true) }}"
    - [ item_key_1, item_key_2 ]
```